# Shuffling text from file by group of data

Tags: python, shell, unix, random, shuffle

I was looking for some approach in Python / Unix Command to shuffle large data set of text by grouping based on first words value like below-

Input Text:

```
"ABC", 21, 15, 45
"DEF", 35, 3, 35
"DEF", 124, 33, 5
"QQQ" , 43, 54, 35
"XZZ", 43, 35 , 32
"XZZ", 45 , 35, 32
```

So it would be randomly shuffled but keep the group together like below

Output Sample-

```
"QQQ" , 43, 54, 35  
"XZZ", 43, 35 , 32
"XZZ", 45 , 35, 32
"ABC", 21, 15, 45
"DEF", 35, 3, 35
"DEF", 124, 33, 5
```

I found solution by normal shuffling, but I am not getting the idea to keep the group while shuffling.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do it using [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html?highlight=collections%20defaultdict#collections.defaultdict). By identifying each line by its first sequence you can sort through them easily and then only sample over the dictionary's keys, like so:

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

# Read all the lines from the file
lines = defaultdict(list)
with open("/path/to/file", "r") as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        s_line = line.split(",")
        lines[s_line[0]].append(line)

# Randomize the order
rnd_keys = random.sample(lines.keys(), len(lines))

# Write back to the file?
with open("/path/to/file", "w") as out_file:
    for k in rnd_keys:
        for line in lines[k]:
            out_file.write(line)
```

Hope this helps in your endeavor.

Comment: This one is still shuffling just random order. I am still unable about the "grouping" of first string of the line

Comment: My bad I did not get what you meant by "grouping".

Comment: Sorry If I failed to explain. As I mentioned "grouping based on first words" , so as you see on the sample output, lines start with "XZZ" and "DEF" are altogether. That's what I meant about grouping by first value. Line would be intact, but similar word that start the line would also be "grouped"

Comment: I edited my answer to match your definition of grouping. Once again my apologies for not reading correctly the first time around.

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks, also for being fast ;D

Answer (score 2):

You could also store each line from the file into a nested list:

```
lines = []
with open('input_text.txt') as in_file:
    for line in in_file.readlines():
        line = [x.strip() for x in line.strip().split(',')]
        lines.append(line)
```

Which gives:

```
[['"ABC"', '21', '15', '45'], ['"DEF"', '35', '3', '35'], ['"DEF"', '124', '33', '5'], ['"QQQ"', '43', '54', '35'], ['"XZZ"', '43', '35', '32'], ['"XZZ"', '45', '35', '32']]
```

Then you could group these lists by the first item with [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter

grouped = [list(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(lines, key = itemgetter(0))]
```

Which gives a list of your grouped items:

```
[[['"ABC"', '21', '15', '45']], [['"DEF"', '35', '3', '35'], ['"DEF"', '124', '33', '5']], [['"QQQ"', '43', '54', '35']], [['"XZZ"', '43', '35', '32'], ['"XZZ"', '45', '35', '32']]]
```

Then you could shuffle this with [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```
import random

random.shuffle(grouped)
```

Which gives a randomized list of your grouped items intact:

```
[[['"QQQ"', '43', '54', '35']], [['"ABC"', '21', '15', '45']], [['"XZZ"', '43', '35', '32'], ['"XZZ"', '45', '35', '32']], [['"DEF"', '35', '3', '35'], ['"DEF"', '124', '33', '5']]]
```

And now all you have to do is flatten the final list and write it to a new file, which you can do with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
with open('output_text.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    for line in itertools.chain.from_iterable(grouped):
        out_file.write(', '.join(line) + '\n')

print(open('output_text.txt').read())
```

Which a gives new shuffled version of your file:

```
"QQQ", 43, 54, 35
"ABC", 21, 15, 45
"XZZ", 43, 35, 32
"XZZ", 45, 35, 32
"DEF", 35, 3, 35
"DEF", 124, 33, 5
```